# Найти определенный объект в массиве объектов?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив объектов. Их достаточно большое количество.
Объекты вида:

```
  {
     id: 123,
     name: 'г. Москва"
  }
```

Как мне быстро найти среди них объект (он гарантировано будет один), свойство `name` которого совпадает с моим указанным (например, "г. Москва") и взять его `id`? Нужен самый оптимальный и быстрый способ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Самым быстрым способом будет создание объекта с ключами-name и доставать просто по ключу.

Если нужно достать именно из массива, то создать 2 массив со значениями name из первого в той же последовательности. После этого искать нужный индекс с помощью `indexOf` и по нему доставать нужный объект.

Но самым простым и читаемым вариантом(но более медленным по сравнению с предыдущими) будет `filter`. Он быстрее перебора массива с помощью `for...in`/`for...of`.

Answer (score 23):

Как оказалось, не все помнят про существование в ES6 метода [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). :)

```js
let cities = [{ id: 121, name: 'г. Урюпинск' }, { id: 122, name: 'г. Париж' }, { id: 123, name: 'г. Москва' }, { id: 124, name: 'г. Штормград' }];
let searchTerm = 'г. Москва';
let cityId = cities.find(city => city.name === searchTerm).id
console.log(cityId);
```

Answer (score 3):

Если ECMAScript - то через [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
var data = [{ id: 123, name: "г. Москва" }, { id: 124, name: "г. Немосква" }];
var cutySearch = "г. Москва";

var cityId = data.filter(function(val) {
  return val.name == cutySearch;
})[0].id;
console.log(cityId);
```

Либо вручную перебирать:

```js
var data = [{ id: 123, name: "г. Москва" }, { id: 124, name: "г. Немосква" }];
var cutySearch = "г. Москва";

var cityId;
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(data[i].name == cutySearch) {
    cityId = data[i].id;
    break;
  }
}
console.log(cityId);
```

Comment: В ES6 стиле ещё симпатичнее - `var cityId = data.filter(val => val.name == cutySearch })[0].id;`

Но с filter есть и минус, если будет необходимо только первое вхождение, цикл в любом случае обойдёт весь массив до конца, но это критично для огромных массивов.

Comment: @PetrChalov , отлично, вы мне про бряк забытый напомнили. Я тут подумал, ведь можно ещё с `reduce` извратиться, но недостаток от `filter` останется.

Comment: А почему filter-то, а не find? afaik, find как раз прекращает перебор после нахождения.

Comment: @Yaant , добавьте ответ с `find`, я про него почему-то не вспомнил.

Comment: @br3t reduce определённо не для этих целей.

Comment: @Yaant это чудо, честно говоря до сих пор не натыкался в документации, find определенно лучше.

 `var cityId = data.find(val => val.name === cutySearch).id;`